# changing default text color web page

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of the text inside the page
I would rather use CSS to make future changes easier.

I have no CSS files yet, I'm starting from scratch here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create a `.css` file (in whatever file system you have), add this line:

```
body
{
    color: green; //Or whatever color you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple easy ways of changing font colors https://jsfiddle.net/93sv9dL4/

```
/*Target the element*/
h1{color: blue;}
h2{color: green;}
h3{color: orange;}
p{color: yellow}
/*use a class*/
.red{color: red}
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the color you use - color:

You can use a hard color (i.e.: red, black, grey, green) that will be interpreted by the browser or you can use a hex code. Adobe Kuler is one of the best tools for that: https://color.adobe.com

You can change the color of text for an entire page by:

```css
body{color: red;}
```

or

```css
body{color: #FF1615;}
```

You can also target the elements like `<h1>` you want:

```css
h1{color: white;}
```

or use a hex color like

```css
h1{color: #FFFFFF;}
```

You can also select ID's

```css
#id_example{color: #FF00FF;}
```

or a class like:

```css
.class_example{color: #000000;}
```

Those are the simplest ways and most common methods.

There is also RGB and RGBO.

CSS is cascading though so if you had your `<body>` one color and then your `<h1>` tags a different color like like above examples the text in `<h1>` would be #FFFFFF and all the rest would be #FF1615. It also goes by specificity. SO, anything with the class: .class_example tag would be: #000000

Let me know if you have any questions or need anything else. Hoped that helped.